# how to compare value of two dictionary "Even trigger"

Tags: python-3.x

I have log file which will update every second. i want to read that file and compare every second so if the value in the second column have changes i will send the full data else i don't do anything.

```
myDictionary:

    {'N': 'D_SPREADER_UNLOCKED_SIGNAL', 'T': '2019-09-20 10:01:27', 'V': '-1'}
    {'N': 'D_SPREADER_RIGHT_LANDED', 'T': '2019-09-20 10:01:27', 'V': '0'}
    {'N': 'C_SPREADER_45_FEET_SIGNAL', 'T': '2019-09-20 10:01:27', 'V': '0'}
    {'N': 'D_LOADCELL4', 'T': '2019-09-20 10:01:28', 'V': '416'}
    {'N': 'D_HOIST_POSITION_(MM)', 'T': '2019-09-20 10:01:28', 'V': '21391'}
    {'N': 'D_LOADCELL1', 'T': '2019-09-20 10:01:28', 'V': '608'}

import time
filepath=r"D:\python\Ram\data1.txt"
f = open(filepath, 'r')
rf=f.readlines()[1:][:-1]
f.close()
result={}
data1=[]
data2=[]
for row in rf:
    word1 = row.strip().replace("\t", ",").replace('\"', '').split(',')
    result={'N': word1[0],'T': word1[1], 'V': word1[2]}
    data1.append(result)

time.sleep(1)
for row in rf:
    word1 = row.strip().replace("\t", ",").replace('\"', '').split(',')
    result={'N': word1[0],'T': word1[1], 'V': word1[2]}
    data2.append(result)

#if column2 value data1 different from column2.value data send data 2 else pass
```

Comment: "VarName" "TimeString" "VarValue"
"D_SPREADER_UNLOCKED_SIGNAL" "2019-09-20 10:01:27" -1
"D_SPREADER_RIGHT_LANDED" "2019-09-20 10:01:27" 0
"C_SPREADER_45_FEET_SIGNAL" "2019-09-20 10:01:27" 0
"D_LOADCELL4" "2019-09-20 10:01:28" 416
"D_HOIST_POSITION_(MM)" "2019-09-20 10:01:28" 21391
"D_LOADCELL1" "2019-09-20 10:01:28" 608

Comment: above is my text file